# Export Org-mode document with Biblatex-style citations and Org-ref

Tags: org-mode, org-ref

With `org-ref` and `biblatex`, I only get the Helm menu for further actions (with `C-c C-o`) on `autocite` citations... `textcite` and `cite` don't respond to the `C-c C-o` prompt. How come?

Also, to be able to export the org document to pdf, I have to manually evaluate code such as this:

```
  (org-ref-link-set-parameters "parencite"
    :export
    (lambda (path desc format)
      (cond
       ((eq format 'latex)
        (if (or (not desc) (equal 0 (search "parencite:" desc)))
            (format "\\parencite{%s}" path)
          (format "\\parencite[%s]{%s}" desc path)
          )))))

  (org-ref-link-set-parameters "textcite"
    :export
    (lambda (path desc format)
      (cond
       ((eq format 'latex)
        (if (or (not desc) (equal 0 (search "textcite:" desc)))
            (format "\\textcite{%s}" path)
          (format "\\textcite[%s]{%s}" desc path)
          )))))
```

Is there a way to automate this so that it is evaluated on start-up and so Org will pick it up when exporting to pdf?

Comment: This suggests something is not working right in your installation.  You should file an issue at https://github.com/jkitchin/org-ref/issues/ with the output of M-x org-ref that is run in a buffer that has that problem.

Comment: John, I will do. Thank you very much for your prompt response and for all your work for the community!!